# Why does my function not work when trying to push values onto my array?

Tags: javascript

```js
  const todo = [{
    task: 'Wash Plates',
    day: 'Monday'
  },{
    task: 'Clean Pc',
    day: 'Tuesday'
  },]


    let addTask = todo.push((todoTask, date) => {
        todo.task = todoTask,
        todo.day = date
    })

    addTask('car', 'monday')




  for (var i = 0; i < todo.length; i++) {
    console.log(`${i+1}. ${todo[i].task} on ${todo[i].day}`);
  }
```

Why is the addTask not a function, even when i use normal functions (not arrows) it has the same result. The loop below is fine and so is the array above. I want to be able push values onto my todo list. Can someone help please.

Comment: You're pushing a function onto the array, not an object.

Comment: `push()` doesn't take a callback?  It takes the values you want to push to the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct notation for an arrow function is this: (args) => {}. addTask is not actually in function format, it just receives the push return, to resolve this do:

```
let addTask = (todoTask, date) => todo.push({task: todoTask, day: date})
```

e.g.

```js
const todo = [{
    task: 'Wash Plates',
    day: 'Monday'
  },{
    task: 'Clean Pc',
    day: 'Tuesday'
  },]


    let addTask = (todoTask, date) => todo.push({task: todoTask, day: date})

    addTask('car', 'monday')




  for (var i = 0; i < todo.length; i++) {
    console.log(`${i+1}. ${todo[i].task} on ${todo[i].day}`);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got `.push` and the arrow function mixed up. Try this:

```js
let addTask = (todoTask, date) => {
  todo.push({
    task: todoTask,
    day: date
  })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`addTask` is not a function. You're calling `todo.push()` with a function as the argument, then you're assigning the return value to `addTask`. `push()` returns the new length of the array, so you're adding the function to the array and then setting `addTask` to the array length.

You need to take the function out of the `push()` argument. Then you need to use correct syntax for an object literal.

```js
const todo = [{
  task: 'Wash Plates',
  day: 'Monday'
}, {
  task: 'Clean Pc',
  day: 'Tuesday'
}, ]


let addTask = (todoTask, date) => todo.push({
  task: todoTask,
  todo: date
})

addTask('car', 'monday')

for (var i = 0; i < todo.length; i++) {
  console.log(`${i+1}. ${todo[i].task} on ${todo[i].day}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing the following function into the end of the `todo` array:

```
(todoTask, date) => { ... }
```

after which the call to [Array.push returns the new length of the `todo` array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), hence you get the length (a number) as a returned value to `addTask`.

The definition of `addTask` function should be:

```
let addTask = (task, day) => todo.push({task ,day});
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the others, but you can change your variable names to allow for the ES6 object construction to be minimized.

```js
const todo = [{
  task: 'Wash Plates',
  day: 'Monday'
}, {
  task: 'Clean Pc',
  day: 'Tuesday'
}, ]


let addTask = (task, day) => todo.push({task, day});

addTask('car', 'monday')

for (var i = 0; i < todo.length; i++) {
  console.log(`${i+1}. ${todo[i].task} on ${todo[i].day}`);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you don't need a separate function do add some values to your array. Try this:

```
array.push({
   task: todoTask,
   day: date
})
```

although if you want to make a function :

```
const addTask = (task, day) => todo.push({task, day})
```

Comment: It is unnecessary to take `todo` as an argument to `addTask` in this way if `addTask` function doesn't return a new array in a functional way.

Comment: you don't need to return an Object if you making some modification in it. because objects are passed by reference in js.

Comment: Yes, and that's why you don't need to take it as an argument. In some functional language where arrays are immutable, `addTask` could have taken `todo` argument and return a mutated array.